# How to navigate to another screen from a Redux form with React navigation?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

Basically I want that within a props.handleSubmit function you can navigate to another screen.

Here is my [code](https://snack.expo.io/@valentinrz14/cmVkdX) :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Store from './Store/Store'
import ScreenSignUp from './Navigation/ScreenSignUp';
import ScreenSignIn from './Navigation/ScreenSignIn';
import ScreenHome from "./Navigation/ScreenHome";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: ScreenHome,
    SignUp: ScreenSignUp,
    SignIn: ScreenSignIn,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'SignIn',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
 export default reduxForm({ 
 form: 'SignInForm',
 onSubmitSuccess : (result, dispatch, props) => {
     props.navigation.navigate('Register');
  },   
  onSubmitFail : () => {
  Toast.show({
    text: "Enter Passport Number",
    duration: 2500,
    position: "top",
    textStyle: { textAlign: "center" }
  });   
  }
  validate,
  })(SignInForm);
```